# How to find communities in a NetworkX Graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx, complex-networks

I am trying to figure out how can I find communities in a Graph in NetworkX that depend on color and weight. I was given a code that evolves a graph from a starting state to a final state and was given the task to find the communities from the final state of it. I have been trying to do it with `nx.to_dict_of_lists()`  and `community.greedy_modularity_communities()`but it did not work. As you can see in the following picture [Graph in final state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRuGg.png) I have the final state of the graph and I should be getting something like:

```
1: [2,3]
2: [7]
3: [0]
4: [1]
5: [6]
6: [5]
7: [4]
```

These results should be based upon color and weight.
However, by doing it with `nx.to_dict_of_lists()` I get the following:

```py
{0: [1, 5, 6, 7], 
 1: [0, 2],
 2: [1, 3, 7],
 3: [2, 4, 7],
 4: [3, 5],
 5: [4, 0],
 6: [0],
 7: [3, 2, 0]}
```

Also, with the `community.greedy_modularity_communities()` I get:

```py
[frozenset({3, 4, 5}), frozenset({0, 1, 6}), frozenset({2, 7})]
```

I would really appreciate if you could help me. Thanks!

Comment: Did you set the weight property when using `community.greedy_modularity_communities()`?

Comment: @SimonThordal Yes, I did use it however it gives me back the same sets.